# Checked radio button in Django form

Tags: django, forms

I'm trying to render in template two radio button. But one of them must be checked initialy.

My form.py:

```
class ChangeAddressForm(forms.Form):
    CHOICES = [('current', ''),
               ('new', '')]

    address = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES, widget=forms.RadioSelect)
```

This is the way I'm writing in template to show them up:

```
{{ address_form.address.0 }} {{ address_form.address.0 }}
```

How can I have the first radio button checked, please?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your CHOICES as

```
CHOICES = (
    (1,'Current'),
    (0,'New')
)
```

And then

```
class ChangeAddressForm(forms.Form):
    current_address = forms.ChoiceField(required = True, choices = CHOICES, widget=forms.RadioSelect(attrs={'class' : 'Radio'}), initial=1)
```